# Select the Element based on dynamicID using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newbie to Jquery and trying to do the following.

I have an ID of an element which is generated by concatenation of a variable string. I need to select that element with this generated ID using JQuery. Please see below for more info..
Lets say I have elements with IDs as follows in a html Page

```
ID1=Test_A_element
ID2=Test_B_element
ID3=Test_C_element
ID4=Test_D_element
```

I have a string variable (x) that contains A or B or C or D. I will generate the ID of this element by simple concatenation as follows

```
ID="Test_"+x+"_element";
```

I need to select the correct Element using Jquery.

Comment: I recommend you read through the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes an hour or two, and repays that time almost immediately.

Comment: `$("#Test_" + x + "_element"); `

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
var jQuerySet = $("#" + ID);
```

Using the DOM:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(ID);
```

Live Example:

```js
var ID =
    "Test_" +
    String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 4))) +
    "_Element";
$("<p>").html("The ID is " + ID).appendTo(document.body);
$("#" + ID).css("color", "blue");
```

```html
<div id="Test_A_Element">Test A</div>
<div id="Test_B_Element">Test B</div>
<div id="Test_C_Element">Test C</div>
<div id="Test_D_Element">Test D</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this page for more details about jQuery selectors:  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp.
Or the more detailed official page: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

In your particular case, you can select an element by id with the following construction: `jQuery("#"+ID)`, or `$("#"+ID)`.